# Shopify Edit Shipping Service Label on Cart and Checkout Pages

Tags: shopify

Is there a way to edit the shipping service label that is displayed to the customer on the cart and checkout pages of a Shopify store? I am using the USPS account connection to grab USPS pricing.

For example: 
USPS Priority Mail 2-day

I want it to display as:

USPS Priority Mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the shipping rate name from Admin -> Settings -> Shipping:

[image]

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see that since I am connecting to my USPS account.

Comment: @tonjaggart Hmm, I don't think you can change the name of carrier-calculated shipping rates. [The doco says you can enable/disable rates](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/settings/shipping/modify-shipping#edit-ccs-rates), but I'd say the names of these rates are not editable.

Comment: @tonjaggart you could possibly use javascript to edit the displayed shipping name on the cart page, but you'd still have the default name in the checkout...

Comment: I have access to the API. Would that help me at all to overwrite the labels with JS?

Comment: @tonjaggart I don't think so... how are you displaying the shipping options on the cart page?

Comment: @ Steph through Shopify's Carrier calculated shipping